# How do I prove $x<y$ and $z<0 \Rightarrow xz>yz$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm new to real analysis, I need help proving a few statements.

I always took them for granted, but ok, how do I prove them?

1. Prove that $x+a =b$ has a unique solution.
2. If $x<y$ and $y<z$ then prove that $x<z$
3. If $x<y$ and $z<0$ then show that $xz > yz$

Here is my attempt,

1)

Let $\alpha$ and $\alpha ' $ be the any $2$ solutions of the equation $x +a =b$ 
$\therefore \alpha + a = b$ and $\alpha ' + a =b$,
$ \alpha = b-a $ and $\alpha ' = b- a$ 
$ \Rightarrow \alpha = \alpha'$

2) Given $x<y$ and $y<z$ 
So, $y - x> 0$ and z-y>0 
$\implies (y-x)+(z-y)>0 \implies x<z$

3) I've no idea where to begin?

Can anyone help me out with the 3rd one? Also please tell if I'm missing **any** steps? Even if they're trivial.

Please also tell me, what should I **look** for while attempting to prove "obvious statements" like these? I'm having a hard time because I'm not even sure what is exactly in this to prove?

Thnx

Comment: What analysis book are you using and what are the definitions and axioms they use.  In most books those are axioms and definitions.  (Are you sure you are expected to prove them?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) can be done more directly.

$x + a = b\implies x + a +(-a) = b+(-a)\implies x + 0 = b-a\implies x = b-a$.

2) I'm not sure how in your text $<$ was defined.  Usually it being transitive is a definition.  Sometimes it is $\le $ that is defined as being transitive and $<$ is defined to be $\le$ and $\ne$.  In which case.

If $x< y$ then $x \le y$ and $x\ne y$.  $y < z$ then $y \le z$ and $y\ne z$.  So $x \le z$ by transitive.  If $x = z$ then $x\le y$ and $y\le z$ so $y \le x$. So $x \le y$ and $y\le x$ so $x = y$ by reflexivity and that's a contradiction.  So $x \ne z$ and $x < z$.

Some book define $x < y$ as $y-x > 0$ and, I think, declare all non-zero reals as either $>0$ or $< 0$.  I haven't had much experience with those axioms. But you proof would work for it.

3) You should have an axiom that is $x < y$ and $z >0$ then $xz < yz$.

ANd you should be able to prove the following propositions:

Prop:  $z > 0 \iff -z < 0$ (and vice versa).

Proof: $z > 0 \implies z + (-z) > 0 + (-z)\implies 0 > -z \implies 0+z > (-z) + z \implies z > 0$.

Prop:  $(-a)b = -(ab)$

Proof:  $(-a)b + ab = (-a + a)b$ (distribution) $= 0*b = ....$ Ooops. we need a third proposition the $0*b = 0$.  So $(-a)b + ab = 0$ so $(-a)b = -(ab)$.

Prop: $0*b = 0$

Proof:  $0  = 0*b + (-0*b) = (0+0)b + (-0*b) = 0*b + 0*b + (-0*b) = 0*b + (0*b + (-0*b) = 0*b + 0 = 0*b$.

So knowing that.

$x < y$ and $z < 0$ means $-z > 0$ means $x(-z) < y(-z)\implies -xz < -yz \implies -xz + xz < -yz + xz \implies 0 < -yz + xz \implies yz < xz$.

but if you are using the $a < b \iff b-a > 0$ definition this may be trickier.

$x < y \implies 0 < (y-x)$ and $z < 0\implies 0 < -z$ and so $0 < -z(y-x) = (-z)y - (-z)x$ and .... so on.... I guess as I'm not as caught up on these definitions and axioms (In particular I forget how $0 < a$ is defined and what the associated axioms are) I should stop making assumptions.  But the result should be mechanical.

Answer (score 3):

With question 2, it isn't at all clear why your last implication is supposed to be true. Instead, note that $x < y$ means that there is some $a > 0$ such that $y = x + a$, and $y < z$ means that there is some $b > 0$ such that $z = y + b$. Thus, $z = y + b = x + (a + b)$, and $a + b > a > 0$, so indeed, $x < z$.

For question 3, again note that $x < y$ means that there is some $a > 0$ such that $y = x + a$. But then $yz = (x + a)z = xz + az$, so $xz = yz + (-az)$, and $-az > 0$ since $-a < 0$ and $z < 0$, so $xz > yz$.

Comment: "With question 2, it isn't at all clear why your last implication is supposed to be true."  Im assuming $(y-x) + (z-y)=y+(-x +z) -y=(y-y) +(-x + z) = (-x + z) > 0\implies z> x$.

Comment: Yes, but that's not in his proof anywhere, and it should be, which is the point.

Comment: Fair nuff.  Still want to know just which axioms he is dealing with.  After all, transitivity of $<$ is usually a given.

Comment: Yeah. I assumed the only one I've ever seen where it isn't an axiom.

Comment: I've seen that.  The definition is: $x < y$ if there exists a positive $a$ so that $x = y-a$ (or equivalently $x+a = y$). Right?  But what are the axioms (and definitions?) about positive numbers?  That if $x$ is positive then $-x$ is negative? And ... how to we get multiplication in?  That if $a > 0; b> 0$ then $ab >0$?

Comment: Which analysis books use those?  I thought Apostle did but I looked it up and he didn't.  I've got Marsden, Apostle and Rudin on my shelves and they all use what, in my bias, I consider the "normal" axioms.  (Albeit Marsden starts with $\le$ as the basic order and Rudin with $<$.)

Comment: You take it generally having already defined the real numbers without talking about the order structure at all. No idea about textbooks, because I've never read an undergraduate mathematics textbook in my life.